# I am trying to get the remaining time until the next day on a certain hour

Tags: java, time, minecraft

So what I have is 3 variable of the hour minutes and seconds of the time i want to countdown towards.

how can I make it to count towards this time that I have and it will output 3 variables that contains the remaining hours minutes and seconds.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please share your existing implementation?

Comment: i dont have. i was hoping to get help on how to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate time difference in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927856/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: its counting up i want it to count down

Comment: Try reversing the parameters.

Comment: which parameters to reverse?

Comment: well this is the thing i dont have code i want code to a system that will give me the remaining time between two different hours minutes and seconds

Comment: Don’t use the accepted answer under the question that @jimmysumshugar linked to. It’s using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, a couple of poorly designed and age-old classes that we should under no circumstances be using any more. There may be other helpful answers there (I haven’t checked yet).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.time.LocalTime` to create the start and end times and loop through all times between them with the specified interval e.g. the following code loops from the `start` until the `end` at an interval of one second.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(10, 20, 15);
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(10, 15, 20);

        // Count down every second from start until end
        for (LocalTime time = start; time.isAfter(end); time = time.minusSeconds(1)) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond()));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10:20:15
10:20:14
10:20:13
...
...
...
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I strongly recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work. This should get you started:

```
    int hour = 14;
    int minute = 23;
    int second = 45;
    
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    ZonedDateTime endTime = LocalDate.now(zone)
            .plusDays(1)
            .atTime(LocalTime.of(hour, minute, second))
            .atZone(zone);
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    Duration remainingTime = Duration.between(now, endTime);
    
    long hoursRemaining = remainingTime.toHours();
    int minutesRemaining = remainingTime.toMinutesPart();
    int secondsRemaining = remainingTime.toSecondsPart();
    
    System.out.format("Remaining: %d hours %d minutes %d seconds%n",
            hoursRemaining, minutesRemaining, secondsRemaining);
```

When I ran this snippet in my time zone just now, the output was:

> Remaining: 15 hours 55 minutes 27 seconds

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.